# inserting space between two characters in a text file with awk or sed

Tags: shell, unix, text, awk, sed

I have the following text file:

```
20170110 120000
'Location    '  67.57-164.07      30.0   3.78 128.6   0.00 270.0
```

Now what I want to is insert a space between the 67.57 and -164.07 so that the text file will now look like:

```
20170110 120000
'Location    '  67.57 -164.07      30.0   3.78 128.6   0.00 270.0
```

I know that I can use an awk or sed command and have looked at information on this but the information available was vague and not specific to what I was looking for.  Do you have any suggestions on what I could do to get the desired results?

Comment: is input file tab separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a space before first `-`:

```
sed "s/-/ &/" file
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a space in front of every `-` not preceeded by space using sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([^[:blank:]a-z]\)-/\1 -/g' file
20170110 120000
'Location-aware    '  67.57 -164.07      30.0   3.78 128.6   0.00 270.0
```

**Edit**: Changed `[^ ]` to `[^[:blank:]a-z]` for suggestion by @Neron-Le-Velu ;D.

Comment: like your approach, maybe change white space by `[:blank:]` and exclude the quoted string to avoid blank in St-Louis :-) +1

Comment: `[:blankety:][:blank:][:blanking:] St-Louis`! I'll try to give it a go...

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\('[^']*[[:blank:]]*\.[0-9]\{1,2\}\)-/\1 -/' YourFile
```

Assuming that the space is to be inserted after first number after the quoted string that have at least 1 decimal value directly followed by a "-"

Not knowing value and format is too lazy to allow specific modification, you should assume some (like "field" size, field format, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some little piece in awk. But it is just working for your special case since there is a fixed value in this one liner.

```
'NR==2{gsub("-164.07"," -164.07")}{ print}' your_file
```

Comment: JFS31, I think the format is not proper of your command, there are few point in here.
i- NR=2, we should do it like NR==2(because = is assignment operator not conditional operator)
ii- Change (-164.07"}{ ) to (-164.07");) else it will give syntax errors.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. The bracket is definitely missing. I'll change that.